# Firing callback on query change in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm looking for solution for paging in routing with react-router and redux.

React-router don't fire callback in `onEnter` hook if only query changes, `Router.run` method is deprecated, so I'm a bit puzzled. Are there any other thing to do besides manually subscribing on location.change or use of react's lifecycle hooks like `willReceiveProps`?

Comment: Won't `componentWillMount` on the component you're "going to" be enough?

Comment: No, because route handler wouldn't be re-mounted on this. I'm fine with `onEnter` for initial loading, but it doesn't fire on query param change

Comment: What about `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Comment: I want to put all logic in router, not components. Of course, react lifecycle hooks will work, and I can listen to history or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the comments, the only hook left to you on the `<Router>` directly is `onUpdate`. You might also be able to intercept query parameters via a custom RoutingContext, but we don't currently consider that a public API.

We're looking to add a better solution for this use case in the future, but the approaches outlined are the only ones available for the 1.0.0 release.

Comment: Didn't know there's such hook in 1.0 router, looks like it's at least undocumented.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this! I've looked all over Route docs, which was the wrong place ))

Comment: how do you fire to current route component an event about querystring change? which event?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using v2.0/v3.0, you can use the route's `onChange` hook to respond to query changes.

```
<Route
  component={...}
  path="..."
  onChange={(nextState, replace, callback) => {
    // Do something in response to a query change...
  }}
/>
```

> **onChange(prevState, nextState, replace, callback?)**
> Called on routes when the location changes, but the route itself
> neither enters or leaves. For example, this will be called when a
> route's children change, or when the location query changes. It
> provides the previous router state, the next router state, and a
> function to redirect to another path. this will be the route instance that triggered the hook. If callback is listed as a 4th argument, this hook will run asynchronously, and the transition will block until callback is called.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#onchangeprevstate-nextstate-replace-callback

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @MattiasWallin, link updated and pasted the relevant text inline.